# How do I removing the <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"> in Json

Tags: json, asmx

I am using asmx as my json call and when I console log to chrome, it has the **"string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"** tag as shown here below.

[image]

How do I remove the  tag? Here is my asmx code:

[image]

Thanks a lot and greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Please don't post code, exceptions, or results as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). They can't be copied (partly) for answering and their "text" won't appear in search engines. Images should only be used as a last resort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone wants to know how to do so. Here it is.

[image]